# Get filtered array (values with the same first letter) from this array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to create a function `indexWords()` that takes an array as parameter and return an object with the first letter of the words as key and each keys list all of the words that start with this letter.

Here an exemple because my english is really bad lol:

```
indexWords(["apple", "car", "cat"]) // output:  {a: ["apple"], c: ["car", "cat"]}
```

so I started to get an array with the first letter and remove duplicates letter by doing like so:

```
indexWords(arr) {    
let firstLetters = [... new Set(arr.map(x => x[0]))]

}
```

But then I need to filter the given `arr` and create a new mapped array for each values that have the same first letter. Basically I should check `if arr[i][0] === firstLetters[0]`, and then `firstLetters[1]` etc. But how to know how many index will be into `firstLetters`  ? I'm lost...

Comment: You can do this with streams using collectors.groupingBy. Im on my phone right now, so i can only tell you the pseudocode. Something like Stream.of(arr).collect(Collectors.groupingBy( word -> word.charAt(0))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce` to build the array as follows.

```js
function indexWords(input) {
  return input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur[0]] ? acc[cur[0]].push(cur) : acc[cur[0]] = [ cur ];
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

console.log(indexWords(["apple", "car", "cat"]));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can I get some explainations please ? because on arr[cur[0]].push(cur) it seems that arr[cur[0]] is an object right ? and push doesn't work only with arrays ? and what does it mean the else acc[cur[0]] = [cur] ? I know how reduce works (accumulator takes the {} value that is declare after the function, and current value would be here each value of the input array but I dont understad the ternary operation please help me understand

Comment: As you know, the initial value of `acc` is {}. And when `"apple"` is put, on callback, it finds if `acc['a']` is existed and if not existed, assign new array with the current value. `acc[cur[0]] = [ cur ]` = `acc["a"] = [ "apple" ]`.
And continue working, and if `acc["a"]` is existed, push the current value to `acc["a"]`. As you see, if `acc['a']` is undefined, I have assigned array value so you can push the value later. Make sense?

Comment: Okay now it makes much more sense, just a last thing, in the case where acc[cur[0]] already exist (in this case its when the current value is "cat") so you said it push the current value to acc[cur[0]] (so where {c : ["car']} it will add "cat" to the array with "car") but you assign the current value to the object acc so how its possible ?

Comment: Ah no because acc[cur[0]] is not the key its the array at this key. Now it makes sense, but wow this is so smart ! How can I train myself to think like that omg

Comment: If `acc[cur[0]] = [ "car" ]` and you need to put `"cat"`, `acc[cur[0]].push(current value)` will be called. So current `acc[cur[0]]` value is `[ "car" ]`, so it's same meaning with `[ "car" ].push("cat")` and the result array will be `[ "cat", "car" ]`.

Comment: Yeah, right `acc[cur[0]]` means same as `acc["c"]` if `cur = "cat"`. And if it works well, can you approve my answer? @YoëlZerbib

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Array.reduce()` method to solve this problem. Please check my solution. (**It also solves the duplicate issue**)

```js
  function indexWords(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((obj, item) => {
      const firstChar = item[0];
      if (!obj[firstChar]) obj[firstChar] = [item];
      else obj[firstChar] = [...new Set([...obj[firstChar], item])];
      return obj;
    }, {});
  }
  console.log(indexWords(["apple", "car", "cat", "cat"]));
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is not a `Set` but a `Map`.

```js
const indexWords = array => array.reduce((map, curr) => map.set(curr[0], ( map.get(curr[0]) || new Array()).concat(curr) ), new Map());

const output = indexWords(["apple", "car", "cat"]);
console.log(Object.fromEntries(output));

// output:  {a: ["apple"], c: ["car", "cat"]}
```

Commented:

```
const indexWords = array =>
  array.reduce((map, curr) =>
    map.set(curr[0], // curr[0] represents the first character. We are going to change the value corresponding to the first character.
    (
      map.get(curr[0]) || new Array()) // initialization (kind of getOrDefault in Java)
      .concat(curr)  // appends the value to the corresponding array
    ), new Map() // we start fresh with a new Map
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let res = _.groupBy(["apple", "car", "cat"], (val)=>(val[0]))
console.log("result",res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

you can also use https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy  to achieve this